# Spring looking for PostgreSql driver, but I'm using JTDS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

Loading a spring cloud dataflow app fails with this log:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
```

But configuration is:

```
spring.jpa.database=sybase
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sybase://xxx:X000/xxxx;autoCommit=false;appName=dataflow
spring.datasource.username=xx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtdatasource.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=datasource-pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=0
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.hikari.transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

PostgreSql is never specified.

Using spring boot 2.3.3

**Update:**

I think something in spring dataflow context is setting the driver, because it works if I create my own configuration class and don't use spring.datasource prefix:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.ds")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.ds.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource sybaseDataSource() {
        return dataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the dependency on pom?

Comment: yes, the jtds dependency is included